# jdbctemplate not acceptin multiple arguments

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am having issue with the query not reading the arguments 'lon' and 'lat'. Is it because it is a nested query? If so then how do I pass the lon and lat to the query?

```
public List<RentalDto> selectRentalsByDistance(Double lon, Double lat) {
        var sql =
                """
                SELECT *
                FROM (
                SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos(radians(lat) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians(lon) )
                + sin( radians(lat) ) * sin( radians(latitude) )) ) AS distance
                FROM rental
                ) AS subquery
                WHERE distance < 25
                ORDER BY distance
                LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
                """;
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rentalDtoRowMapper, lon, lat);
}
```

Comment: how would jdbctemplate know that lat / lon are parameters, they look just like strings. You should use named parameters probably? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate